# Vagrant proxy works for `apt-get` but not for `ping`

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

In Ubuntu Xenial guest machine, I was unable to run `apt-get update`, and also unable to `ping www.google.com`. Then I set /etc/apt/apt.conf proxy settings:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://my.proxy.com:80";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://my.proxy.com:80";
```

Then I was able to run `apt-get`. Then I tried

```
export http_proxy=http://my.proxy.com:80
export https_proxy=https://my.proxy.com:80
```

But I am still unable to `ping www.google.com`. It just hangs with this message

```
PING www.google.com (74.125.202.105) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

So I tried using the vagrant-proxyconf plugin, version 1.5.2. I set the proxy settings in ~/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-proxyconf")
        config.proxy.http     = "http://my.proxy.com:80"
        config.proxy.https    = "https://my.proxy.com:80"
        config.proxy.no_proxy = "localhost,127.0.0.1,.example.com"
    end
    # ... other stuff
end
```

But I am still unable to ping www.google.com, whether I `export` the `http_proxy` settings or unset them.

I also tried some suggestions from some other answers, such as

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
end
```

and

```
config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |vb|
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--cableconnected1', 'on']
end
```

But none of this works. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ping` is using ICMP protocol (see [RFC 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792)) so you should check if your firewall is not blocking this protocol.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks. I was using `ping` as a general way of testing if I had internet access, without actually trying to run other internet-dependent commands. `curl` and other `git submodule` commands that were failing before are now working since installing `vagrant-proxyconf`. Thanks. If not for you, I may not have tried again!